# Web AppBuilder DE - Use an uploaded shapefile to query

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, query, feature-layer, arcgis-web-appbuilder

The shapfile is zipped and uploaded through the "Add Data" widget. I am looking to use an customized widget to read the feature layer from the upload and query another feature layer. Since the uploaded layer is based on feature collection instead of REST URL, server-side query is not an option to get the geometry out of the uploaded layer to fulfill the `query.geometry`. So is there another way to use the uploaded layer to query another feature layer?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. Turns out to be simple: the `graphics` property of the uploaded layer contains every feature with its attributes and geometry. So I can loop through each `graphic` in the `graphics` array and assign `graphic.geometry` to `query.geometry` to do spatial query on another feature layer.